# Build FFmpeg with xCode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ffmpeg, ios7

Does anyone know how to compile FFmpeg with xCode 5?

My configure part:

> ./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
>   --disable-ffserver --enable cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --enable-neon --disable-avfilter \ --disable-bsfs \ --enable-avresample --enable-swresample --disable-iconv --enable-gpl \ --disable-demuxers --enable-demuxer=rtsp --enable-demuxer=rtp --enable-demuxer=mpegts \ --disable-decoders --enable-decoder=mp2 --enable-decoder=mp3 --enable-decoder=mpeg2video --enable-decoder=ac3 - enable-decoder=dvbsub --enable-decoder=h264 \ --disable-parsers --enable-parser=mpegvideo - enable-parser=mpeg4video --enable-parser=mpegaudio --enable-parser=dvbsub\ --disable-muxers --disable-encoders --disable-filters \ --disable-protocols --enable-protocol=http --enable-protocol=rtp --enable-protocol=udp --enable-protocol=tcp \ --disable-swscale-alpha \ --disable-armv5te \ --disable-armv6 \ --disable-armv6t2 \ --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin --as='/usr/local/bin/gas preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin'
>   --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
>   --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk'
>   --enable-pic --disable-bzlib

It works with xCode 4 (different Compiler-Path)

Error-Message:

```
./configure: line 3763: nm: command not found
```

Comment: `nm` / xcode command line tools are installed?

Comment: This is a part of a script file that I execute with the Terminal.. Is there a change to xCode 4? Is there a need to install the command line tools seperatly?

Comment: Yes, after I installed xCode5 the command line tools were deleted... So the answer was to reinstall the command lines tools

Answer (score 2):

```
./configure --prefix=armv7s --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avresample --enable-cross-compile --sysroot="/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk" --target-os=darwin --cc="/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" --extra-cflags="-arch armv7s -mfpu=neon -miphoneos-version-min=7.0" --extra-ldflags="-arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=7.0" --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a9 --enable-pic
```

**EDIT**:
Download my script and run from:
[Installing ffmpeg ios libraries armv7, armv7s, i386 and universal on Mac with 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003034/installing-ffmpeg-ios-libraries-armv7-armv7s-i386-and-universal-on-mac-with-10/19370679#19370679)

Comment: Thanks for the great script.. But I have one problem with the clang compiler in xcode 5... There is only noisy audio playback by decode mp2. The problem doesn't occurs with xcode 4 (gcc-Compiler). If I disable asm then then the problems also doesn't occurs. Have you a idea for this error?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ciphor/ffmpeg4ios

this probably is what you looking for. Get their build script and study. Change the SDK to your 7.0. It'll compile, at least for me on my Xcode5.

UPDATE: search for ffmpeg4ios.

Comment: That link now leads to a domain squatter.